# How to I make a count on specific category when querystring is empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

*I have a menu on my masterpage / defaultpage where I'm listing x categories.
I would like to make a count of how many products there are in each category.*

EX:

Bananas(20)

Apples(8)

Strawberries(5)

*So far, I have this:*

```
 var listSubMenu = __account.GetAllProductCategories();
 var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < listSubMenu.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var r = listSubMenu.Rows[i];

        var catid = Request.QueryString["thespecific_category_id_but_how_do_i_get_it?"];
        var count = __account.GetSpecificCategory(id);

        sb.AppendFormat(String.Format(@"<li{0}><a href='/account/products.aspx?categoryid={0}'>{1} ({2})</a></li>", r["cat_id"], r["cat_name"], count.Rows.Count));

    }
    active_sub_products.Text = sb.ToString();

My DataTable:
public DataTable GetAllProductCategories()
    {
        const string request =
        @"
            SELECT * FROM products_category
            WHERE cat_active = 1
            ORDER BY cat_name ASC
        ";
        using (var query = new MySqlCommand(request))
        {
            return __dbConnect.GetData(query);
        }
    }
```

Obiously i need the specific categoryid, but how to I request that without having querystrings running since it is on the default page.
Am I missing something obious?

Thanks alot.

Comment: I think your structure is not suitable for it. To know it exactly, i would have to see what the "__account" is, and what significant properties / methods you have available

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through your categories and get the ID from there. Not from the querystring since that is related to you page (as you wrote yourself as well).

Given your example, I would expect that  __account.GetAllProductCategories() would return already the ID's you need

In that case you would use something like

```
var catid = listSubMenu.id;
```

But id depends on the type of what your __account returns.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct in my guess at your result schema from GetAllProductCategories()...

["cat_id"]["cat_name"]

[1][Apples]

[2][Bananas]

[3][Oranges]

```
var cat_id = r["cat_id"]
```

or possibly

```
var cat_id = Int32.Parse(r["cat_id"])
```

I would also change:

```
sb.AppendFormat(String.Format(@"<li{0}><a href='/account/products.aspx?categoryid={0}'>{1} ({2})</a></li>", r["cat_id"], r["cat_name"], count.Rows.Count));
```

To:

```
sb.AppendFormat(String.Format(@"<li><a href='/account/products.aspx?categoryid={0}'>{1} ({2})</a></li>", cat_id, r["cat_name"], count.Rows.Count));
```

(There are two changes, (1) <li{0}> to <li> {proper html syntax} and (2) r["cat_id"] to cat_id {you already have it in a variable and string.Format doesn't mind recasting to a string for you})

Beyond that I would suggest looking into an ORM like LinqToSql so you could work directly with objects...

Comment: hey. Yeah, the li{0}, is just because i'm replying a css class to the list, nothing else. Forgot to erase that. About replacing r["cat_id"] with cat_id, it is just me, to quick with my fingers sorry. :)

Comment: Hmm... another take on the question asked... are you trying to figure out how to determine which link the user clicked on so you can show the appropriate products?

Answer (score 0):

First render the category links in the master page:

** When you call GetAllProductCategories, each row of the result will have at least two columns (cat_id and cat_name).

When you get each row by index (var r = listSubMenu.Rows[i]) the row it returns will have the cat_id and cat_name for that record,  I added (var name = r["cat_name"]) for illustration.

If you debug this and step through you should see each iteration through the for loop gives the id variable the next category's id which is then used in the line (var count = __account.GetSpecificCategory(id);)

```
var listSubMenu = __account.GetAllProductCategories();
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < listSubMenu.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var r = listSubMenu.Rows[i];

    var id = Int32.Parse(r["cat_id"]);
    var name = r["cat_name"];

    var count = __account.GetSpecificCategory(id);

    sb.AppendFormat(String.Format(@"<li{0}><a href='/account/products.aspx?categoryid={0}'>{1} ({2})</a></li>", r["cat_id"], r["cat_name"], count.Rows.Count));

}
active_sub_products.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Then into another textbox or area of the actual page "products.aspx"

```
var sbProducts = new StringBuilder();
var selectedCat = Request.QueryString["categoryid"];

if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(selectedCat))
{
    var selectedCatId = Int32.Parse(selectedCat);
    var products = __account.GetSpecificCategory(selectedCatId);

    for(int j = 0; j < products.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
         // ... do product listing stuff here
         // sbProducts.Append(...);
    }
}
else
{
    sbProducts.AppendLine("Invalid Category Id Selected!");
}
active_selected_products.Text = sbProducts.ToString();
```

** Note: when you call Request.QueryString["value"] it will either:

1. Return null indicating that there isn't a querystring parameter with a matching name

   or
2. Return the string representing the content between value= and the end of the url or the next & found.

** this isn't fully production quality code, there are additional checks you should be doing on the query string value, switch to tryparse for example, check number of products returned and show "No products found for that category" ... etc **

Comment: cant see how that would work since there is no querystring value.

Comment: I need to retrieve the speficic id's from my category databasetable.

Comment: I need to make a count on the specific categories. Obviously it would be easy if the querystring has a value, but since it is on the masterpage/defaultpage it hasn't. How to I compensate for the querystring value?

Comment: The call to GetAllProductCategories() doesn't require a category Id so it doesn't need the querystring value.  This section is on the masterpage.  The second code block wouldn't be in the master page, it would be in the Products.aspx page with the assumption that you would only be on the Products page if there was a category to display (i.e. a categoryid in the querystring).

Comment: If you did want to show the product list in the master page when there was a querystring value of categoryid (i.e. user could be in the aboutus.aspx page and click a link on the left and see the product list while still on aboutus.aspx) then it's a bit more dicey but still possible...

Comment: The one other possible scenario I think you might be aiming for is conditional formatting (i.e. highlight, bolding, underline, etc) of the "Bananas(20)" when it is displaying in the details page, this can be handled by getting var catid = Request["categoryid"] above the for loop and checking each category inside the loop: if(catid != null && catid == r["cat_id"]) { /* change css class */ }